# Redirect only from the address port number

Tags: docker, go, post

I've two containers running in docker.
My API (and standard part) is `/abc/{xyz}/xmc`, where `xyz` is, of course, dynamic as this is provided by the user while sending a "POST" request.
This API is running on both port 8080 and 3000 like:

```
http://localhost:3000/abc/nv8vhvv/xmc

http://localhost:8080/abc/chjbc8c/xmc
```

If a user sends a "POST" request to `http://localhost:8080/abc/chjbc8c/xmc`, I want to (internally in the golang file) redirect it to `http://localhost:3000/abc/chjbc8c/xmc`. How can I do this in golang?

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        redirectURI := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:3000%v", r.RequestURI)
        http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURI, 307)
    }
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/abc/nv8vhvv/xmc", redirect)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I got a 404 Not Found

Comment: I changed "/abc/nv8vhvv/xmc" to "/abc/{xyz}/xmc" is this okay?

Comment: If you need to route everything, that comes to "/abc/" it is better to update HandleFunc on "http.HandleFunc("/abc/, redirect)". The r.RequestURI will be passed as-is to the next API on port 3000.

Comment: If you have 404 - add something like "fmt.Println(r.RequestURI)" to the  "redirect" function to see if the request reached this function. If it is - then debug API which sits on the port 3000

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add something like "fmt.Println(r.RequestURI)" to the "redirect" function, and I think the request doesn't reach this function.